# How to get to Old Trafford from Piccadilly station?

Tags: public-transport, uk, manchester

I'm planning to visit Old Trafford during my travel to UK.

I already know that going from London to Manchester is by using train that stops in Manchester Piccadilly. However I'm a bit confused on how to go to Old Trafford Stadium from Manchester Piccadilly station. Google Maps gave me "Walk for 52 mins" even after I chose "using public transport".

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a railway station at Old Trafford itself, handily called "Manchester United Foodball Ground". Looking at the [Official directions and map](http://www.manutd.com/en/Visit-Old-Trafford/Maps-And-Directions.aspx) it looks to be right by the stadium, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_United_Football_Ground_railway_station) concurs.

The [Manchester Sport Website](http://www.manchester.com/sport/united/old-trafford-travel.php#train) suggests that trains to Old Trafford depart from Manchester Picaddilly, so that should make things easy. However, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_United_Football_Ground_railway_station) suggests trains only stop there on match days, so it depends if you're going to see the stadium, or a match there.

There are [two](http://www.manchester.com/sport/united/old-trafford-travel.php#tram)  Metrolink tram stations a short walk away, Exchange Quay and Old Trafford. If it isn't a match day, your best bet is probably to change onto the tram to get there.

Comment: The train only runs on match days - there are special trains that run just for football fans.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to a match, there is a station called "Manchester United Football Ground" that you can get a direct train to - from Piccadilly, these trains leave from platform 14, which is not in the main station; you should use the bridge that is at the far end of the platforms from the station buildings to reach platform 14.  Trains to this stop only run on match days, so if you're going for a visit, then you can't use this option, and your best option will be the tram.

Google Maps wasn't loaded with Greater Manchester public transport until 2014, which is why your Google search didn't help.  If you do that search now, it will advise you to use a Metrolink (tram).

After arrival at Manchester Piccadilly railway station, walk to the end of the platforms and go through the barriers to get into the concourse.  Then turn left and there is a lift and some elevators going down - these are signposted "Metrolink" and also "taxi" and lead to the tram stop, which is at a lower level than the main railway station.

For Old Trafford, you can board any tram headed for Altrincham, Eccles, MediaCity, St. Werburgh's Road, East Didsbury or Manchester Airport.  From an Eccles or MediaCity service, you get off at Exchange Quay; from any other service, you get off at Old Trafford.  Both stops are about five minutes walk from the football ground.  Note that trams to Bury or Rochdale go in the wrong direction; do not board one of these.

From Exchange Quay, you need to use the bridge across the canal, and you should be able to see the ground once you're over the bridge.

From Old Trafford, walk past the cricket ground, which is on your left as you come off the tram, and you should be able to see the football ground.

Answer (score 3):

[This link](http://www.traveline-northwest.co.uk/journeyplanner/enterJourneyPlan.do) might help you find your way around. I've never used the public transport in Manchester but I'm sure there will be a bus.